# How to use Yii2 UploadFile class to recive a POST request with an image

Tags: rest, yii, upload

i was trying to use the "UploadFile" to upload a file that its been send using a POST request (for exapmle from a movile device), but i was not able to doit, i follow the UploadFile tutorial of Yii2.0 guide of the official guide but not good results.

This is my controller: forntend\controllers\Upload

```
namespace forntend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use frontend\models\UploadForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

    class UploadController extends Controller
    {
      public function actionUpload()
      {
        $model = new UploadForm();
         if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
                $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');    
                if ($model->validate()) {                
                    $model->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
                }
      }

    return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
        }
    }
```

This is my model:  /frontend/model/UploadForm

namespace app\models;

```
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

/**
 * UploadForm is the model behind the upload form.
 */
class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile|Null file attribute
     */
    public $file;

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['file'], 'file'],
        ];
    }
}
```

should not this work when i send i POST request to ...localhost/mysite/upload/upload ?

Thanks for any help!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

for upload in yii ckeck this link
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/

Comment: Thanks!!!!, will give a deeper look, its Yii 1.1 but i will try to use the same logic in yii 2.0, and also using REST instead of a form, THATKSS!!!! for you time , i will post my result for other users!!

Comment: if I want to use REST (POST) instead of a form what should be the correct changes, im trying this,
1- I remove the view, and the  $this->render('create', array('model'=>$model)); in the controller, but im missing some concept, and a basic one!!!! but not know how to fix!!